# The injective tensor product of $\mathfrak{L}^{\infty}$-spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

In 1968, Lindenstrauss and Pelczynski introduced the following class of Banach spaces:

A Banach space $X$ is said to an $\mathfrak{L}^{p}_{\lambda}$-space, $p \in [1,\infty], \lambda \in [1,\infty)$, if for each finite dimensional subspace $Y \subset X$, there exists a finite dimensional subspace $Z$ of $X$ containing $Y$ such that $d(Z,\ell^{p}_{n}) < \infty$, where $n$ is the dimension of $Z$ and $d(V,W)$ is the Banach Mazur distance between two Banach spaces $V$ and $W$.
$X$ is called an $\mathfrak{L}^{p}$-space if it is an $\mathfrak{L}^{p}_{\lambda}$-space for some $\lambda$.

Another characterization of $\mathfrak{L}^{\infty}$-spaces involves the injectivity of the second dual : a Banach space $X$ is an $\mathfrak{L}^{\infty}$-space iff $X^{**}$ is injective.
 Where an injective Banach space is a one that is complemented in any Banach space that contains it.

I'm trying to prove the following exercise from Ryan's book: "Introduction to tensor product of Banach spaces":

" If $X$ and $Y$ are $\mathfrak{L}^{\infty}$-spaces, then so is the injective tensor product $X \hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon} Y$."

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.